# In HBase, how to store a List or Array struct

Tags: hbase

I have some data, looks like this:

{'a-name': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3' ...]}

Now, I will store to HBase, the column name is `a-name`, how to store the value(['v1', 'v2', 'v3' ...])?

Answer (score 1):

Values in HBase as stored as just a set of bytes, which means that serialization and deserialization of your array is responsibility of your application. You can manually do it by using Writables (see example below), or use Avro/Thrift/JSON/etc. to serialize-deserialize your data

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
public class test {
    public static Writable toWritable(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Writable[] content = new Writable[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            content[i] = new Text(list.get(i));
        }
        return new ArrayWritable(Text.class, content);
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> fromWritable(ArrayWritable writable) {
        Writable[] writables = ((ArrayWritable) writable).get();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(writables.length);
        for (Writable wrt : writables) {
            list.add(((Text)wrt).toString());
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> arr = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
        HTable table = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create(), "t1");
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("key1"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("f1"), Bytes.toBytes("a"), WritableUtils.toByteArray(toWritable(arr)));
        table.put(p);
        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("key1"));
        Result r = table.get(g);
        ArrayWritable w = new ArrayWritable(Text.class);
        w.readFields(
                new DataInputStream(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("f1"), Bytes.toBytes("a"))
                        )
                )
        );
        ArrayList<String> arr2 = fromWritable(w);
        System.out.println(arr2.toString());
    }
}
```

Here are some more general code for serializing/deserializing different types into writables: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/mr/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/hadoop/util/WritableUtils.java

Comment: How we can put WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema] into Hbase, GenericRowWithSchema implements Serializable. eg. Let's say I have Array[Struct<first:String,second:Int>] and I want to put such array into hbase. If you have an example will help me.